# Is there any framework with a built in crop image tool?

Tags: php

I'm creating a site using php with a user system and I want the user to able to upload a profile picture and crop it as it like. 
I want my code to be able to save the user choice picture and it's cropped version on a file system.
The problem is I saw some tutorials online and they're overtly complex for my level (i'm kinda a begginer). Do you know any kinda of tools or framework that could help me?